# Struct Initialization differnece

Tags: c

Given a struct in C defined as follows:

```
struct Person {
   const char *name;
   int age;
}
```

What are the differences between the two declarations below? I was confused when the struct keyword would precede the initialization below:

```
int main() {
   struct Person John = { .name = "John", .age = 10 };
      
   Person Jane = { .name = "Jane", .age = 10 };
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: (2) doesn't compile in C. It would compile in C++, if `name` was `const char *`.

Comment: C requires a `typedef`, e.g. `typedef struct Person Person;` before using `Person` without the `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the struct in this way:

```c
struct Person {
   const char *name;
   int age;
}
```

Then (1) compiles while (2) does not, since the type of the struct is `struct Person`, not `Person`. "struct" is required.

```c
// (1)
struct Person John = { .name = "John", .age = 10 };
// (2)
Person Jane = { .name = "Jane", .age = 10 };
```

However, if you use typedef:

```c
typedef struct person_t {
   const char *name;
   int age;
} Person;
```

Then you can use both `struct person_t` and `Person` as the latter is an alias of the former.